# Lawn Shed Over Asphalt, BUT Using 4x4 Foundational Posts Buried With Concrete To Secure To Ground

Tags: structural, shed, asphalt

I have REALLY old asphalt along the side of the house, like 30+ years old. It doesn't appear to have any sinking or cracking and has held up better than 15+ year old asphalt my dad had poured elsewhere on the same property. I have read so many posts about NOT using asphalt as the "foundation" or floor of a shed. Part of the reasoning has to do with asphalt not offering a way to truly secure the frame to the ground. Hence my question:

I would like to build a 12'W x 8'D shed over the asphalt BUT cut out sections of asphalt:

A) at each corner, and

B) every 4' in between corner posts.

The 4x4 posts would act as perimeter foundational posts, concreted in (like you would fence posts).

**OPTIONAL:** In order to block a bunch of water from getting at the bottom plates of the framing [2x4 pressure treated, ground contact lumber] (thus limiting deterioration over time), I am considering pouring a concrete skirt along the perimeter. Basically using the posts as framing guides, nail up 2x4s on either side and pour concrete with reinforcing fiber. Then I can build the shed framing off the top of the concrete skirt (and the siding will lip over the edge of the concrete... and a little caulk for good measure). The only area the concrete perimeter skirt would not be is the 6' total width for the side-by-side doors (that will face the lowest side of the ground-grade (there is a slight grade on the asphalt of maybe 2 degrees or so).

Framing will be standard, 2x4's every 24", etc.

As most everyone else who has asked a similar question, I hate to waste, in my case, what appears to be a perfectly good, solid, non-settling asphalt pad that has thus far held up to all the elements in direct exposure.

This will solely be used for a riding mower, push mower, weed eater, and other lawn equipment.

This type of project is totally new to me. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Including:

1. CAN I build this on asphalt using the cemented-in structural posts to "secure" the building to the ground? And if so,
2. Is the concrete perimeter skirting a good idea?
3. How deep (and thus total length) those 4x4 posts should be for structural integrity if I want 8' above the ground for height inside the shed.

Comment: You might want to peruse this document., which suggests a way to anchor to asphalt  http://www.greenhouse.cornell.edu/structures/factsheets/pgm.pdf on Pages 8&9. Steel rod 18" long driven through the blacktop, into the soil below with a sledgehammer. Drill a hole in the plate first....

Comment: does it need to withstand tornadoes or earthquakes at your location?

Comment: No earthquakes. We have occasional tornados in the area. I've thankfully never had to deal with one directly.